# How to programmatically manipulate contents of a file in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to read in a file and as I view each character, if I find a tab character I want to replace it with 2 spaces.

How can i read and modify the contents of a file (at the same time) using Scala?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: retrieve the string from the file

```
  val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("C:/Devs/Scala/Test1/src/abc.txt").mkString
```

Step2: define a function that removes the tabs and replace it with two spaces

```
def transform(S:String): String = {
  return S.flatMap { case '\t' => "  "   case c => s"$c" }
}
```

Step3: use this function

```
println(transform(lines))
```

Input:

abcdefgh    b

Output:

abcdefgh<2 spaces>b

Full code

```
def transform(S:String): String = {
return S.flatMap { case '\t' => "  "   case c => s"$c" }
}

def main(args: Array[String]) {
val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("C:/Devs/Scala/Test1/src/abc.txt").mkString    
println(lines) // displays abcdefgh b
println(transform(lines)) //displays abcdefgh  b
}
```

Hope that helps